# Trouble Installing Ubuntu on an old PC with USB stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, flash

So far I have:

1. downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS from the site.
2. Converted the ISO file to IMG. (I used Unetbootin, I'm not completely sure I did this right.) I selected disk image, ISO, and browsed to find my Ubuntu ISO file. I saved it to a 4 GB flash drive.
3. I put the flash drive in my parents' old HP Pavilion. I rebooted, and hit escape to get to the boot menu.
4. I could see my flash drive as an option. I selected it and hit enter.

--And then Windows XP just starts up like always.--

Even though I select my flash drive from the boot menu, Windows XP loads up. I'm not a computer wiz, and this is my first attempt to play around with Linux. I heard using a cd is easier, but the cd drive on this pc is toast.

Answer (score 0):

go into the bios and set the boot order to allow the usb before the hard drive. also im not familiar with your choice of iso burner, i recomend blackbox iso, its free... shouldn't have to convert to .img, just burn the image straight to the flash.  another option might be to use booti on a cd, then select the usb, or cd of your choice.

Comment: Ok, I went into the BIOS. The Boot Device Priority options are:

Floppy Group
HDD Group
CD-ROM Group
Network Boot Group
Disabled 

I'm not sure which - if any- of those options is my USB drive. 

But when I enter the boot menu from startup, I can see my USB drive and select it. Shouldn't that override any boot device priority?

I have to make the bootable drive on a mac. That's why I didn't use blackbox.

Comment: OK, I found my flash drive in the BIOS. It was filed under HDD Group. And it's listed as second priority to regular Windows. The only problem is that I can't move it up in the list. The instructions say to use the <+> and <-> keys to move them, but pressing the keys does nothing.

Comment: With an older PC, it's quite possible that booting from USB devices is not supported by the BIOS. You may have to source a working optical drive (computer recycling centers often sell used gear cheaply).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to try same process with the help of [Linux Live Usb Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/download)

I am always using It and It work perfectly!!